# MongoDB sorted query returning duplicate items even though items are not duplicated in the database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using a MongoDB on Atlas. I am querying the database from a python script using the pyMongo library.

Version: Python: 3.8.2, MongoDB: 4.4.8

I have a curious problem that for a query to the database that I sort by a given column, I get back duplicate entries in the returned list, even though through the web frontend to access the MongoDB (http://https://cloud.mongodb.com/) I can query the database and do not find duplicate records in the database itself.

An extract of my python code is as follows:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user:passwd@cluster0.ubw9u.mongodb.net/annabot?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
annadb=client.annabot
products_collection=annadb.products

...

query={"$and":[{"prio_brand":True},{'sizes_available_scan_time':{"$exists": False }}]}
scan_item_list=products_collection.find(query).sort("value_score",pymongo.DESCENDING)

for a in range(10):
    item=scan_item_list[a]
    print(item['url'])
```

The output of this code snippet is as follows:

```
2050947061/articles/ZZO19EP23-Q00
1221383231/articles/ZZO17RQ08-K00
2116916381/articles/HU121I0D5-K11
2116916381/articles/HU121I0D5-K11
1487759261/articles/GU121B05H-K11
999470601/articles/ZZO17RQ35-A00
2050947061/articles/ZZO19EP23-M00
999470601/articles/HU121D11P-Q11
999470601/articles/HU121D11P-Q11
1915794391/articles/GU121E0DQ-J11
```

Note that the 3rd and 4th items are identical as are the 8th and 9th items.
But a query of the MongoDB for either of the specific URLs returns a single record in each case.

Any ideas why this might be the case? Why would a query from pyMongo return a list that has duplicate entries when they are actually not duplicated in the database?

Comment: Can you print all values of the scan_item_list? for a in range(len(scan_item_list))

Comment: len(scan_item_list) doesn't work as this is a list of MongoDB cursors. scan_item_list_len=products.collection.count_documents(query) shows there are 588 records found. I changed the code and ran it to output the full list, although it is so long, that I cannot easily copy it all so as to paste it here. But also not sure what value the list of the 588 items would be in investigating this.